# how to proceed to html.actionlink inside ajax success

Tags: c#, jquery, .net

I have a HTML Actionlink as follows:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Next", "Delivery", "Cart", new object { }, new { @class = "button", @id = "next" })
```

Then, I have a jquery click event on that button that makes an ajax call.  That looks like this:

```
$("#next").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var code = $("#school").val();
            var student = $("#student").val();
            if (code != "" && student != "")
            {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("CheckSchoolCode", "Cart")',
                data: {
                    code: code
                },
                dataType: "text",
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    if(data != "")
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $("#message").html("School Code not found.  Please verify you have the right code.");
                    }
```

How do I proceed to the actionlink destination inside of the "if" block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (data != "") {
    window.location.assign($('#next').prop('href'));
}
```

You could simply do `$('#next').click();`, but I prefer not to manually trigger UI events.

Comment: After a click, it seems it will fall down to the same ajax query.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you prefer not to manually trigger UI events?

Comment: @Inanikian I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: @ZiNNED simply because IMO they should be left for the UI to raise. It  feels wrong to me to raise a `click`, for example, when one did not happen.

Comment: If it works then it is ok. Because each time you do the `$('#next').click()` inside the 'if' clause, it will call again the attached event.